# Running test cases selectively with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

There is a total of 20 test case files. I want to test a particular set of 10 test cases. Is there any script file or any other method to run the test cases selectively with Mocha?

Comment: yes i am asking about JavaScript Mocha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two principal ways to specify a subset of tests to run:

1. You can give Mocha the name of the file that contains the tests you want to run:

   ```
   $ mocha path/to/file
   ```

   It is possible to give paths to multiple files if needed. For instance, if you have 10 test files and want to run all the tests from only 2 of them, you could give the paths of the 2 files.

   This method relies on you splitting your tests into separate files according to a logic that suits your situation.
2. You can use the `--grep` option:

   ```
   $ mocha --grep pattern
   ```

   The pattern is a regular expression that Mocha will use to test each test title. Each test for which the pattern matches will be run.

The two methods could be combined to run only tests that match a pattern and that are from one specific file: `$ mocha --grep pattern path/to/file`

Comment: How would I do this in code rather than the terminal? I am creating a ui to selectively choose which tests to run. The problem is that once a test file has been loaded it will continue to be run each time I call mocha.run(). Is there a grep option I can pass into that function so that I can dynamically change what is run?

Answer (score 2):

```
mocha.describe("test1", () => {
    mocha.it("test1_1", (done) => {
        done();
    })
    mocha.it.only("test1_2", (done) => {
      done();
    })
})
OutPut : 
 test2
✔ test2_2 //because of it.only
```

Answer (score 1):

Following command works for me

```
$ node_modules/.bin/mocha test/file1.js test/file2.js
```