# Run and debug in vs code (windows) - Mocha grep option via launch.json giving Error: No test files found (or running all tests rather than pattern)

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Basic configuration in launch.json is running all mocha tests ok in vs code (windows).

When try to add --grep option, unable to get expected pattern matching behavior (ie only run matching tests). With various combinations tried, I get no tests found error, or run all tests.

Note - I'm able to get grep option working with command line (test:grep script - though pattern text is manually input).

Expect --grep 'CURRENTTEST' to only run test with this string in describe (ie 1- passing test in example).
This is the behaviour I get from running command line with grep option as below;
`mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register "spec/**/*.ts" --grep CURRENTTEST`

Actual behaviour with launch.json as shown:
`Error: No test files found: "C:\\temp\\Min code grep test/spec/**/*.spec.ts --grep 'CURRENTTEST'"`
Some other combos attempted ran all tests (rather than pattern matched tests).

Other combinations of args attempted;

- Having grep option on same line as test location, and as separate line underneath.
- Surrounding pattern with single quotes, double quotes (with escape slash), and nothing.

Previous related (but not duplicate) questions;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012417/20429097
[Running test cases selectively with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936728/running-test-cases-selectively-with-mocha)
https://mochajs.org/#-grep-regexp-g-regexp

## Code;

`export function testFn(): number { return 1; }`

## Tests;

```
describe('CURRENTTEST test pass', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(testFn()).to.equal(1);
  });
});
describe('test fail', () => {
  it('should fail', () => {
    expect(testFn()).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

## launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
////////////////////////////// basic config to run all tests - works //////////////////////////////////////
    {
      "name": "mocha tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*.spec.ts",
        "--no-timeouts",
        "--colors",
        "--recursive",
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      // "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      // "console": "integratedTerminal",
    },

/////////////////////// grep config to run CURRENTTEST only - doesn't work ////////////////////////////
    {
      "name": "mocha CURRENTTEST",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*.spec.ts --grep 'CURRENTTEST'",
        "--no-timeouts",
        "--colors",
        "--recursive",
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      // "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
  ]
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "min code grep test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "latest",
    "@types/mocha": "latest",
    "@types/node": "latest",
    "chai": "latest",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "latest",
    "ts-node": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "latest",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "latest",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "latest",
    "eslint-config-google": "latest",
    "eslint-config-standard": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register './spec/**/*.spec.ts'",
    "test:grep": "mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register \"spec/**/*.ts\" --grep"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every argument should be a new element in the array, like:

```
{
      "name": "mocha CURRENTTEST",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*.spec.ts",
        "--grep",
        "CURRENTTEST",
        "--no-timeouts",
        "--colors",
        "--recursive",
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      // "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
```

Comment: @J12345678910 Glad it helped! It is a bit of a shame, because VS Code's documentation doesn't specify this requirement (that it expects every "space separated values" to be a new element in the "args" array) explicitly. I could not find it anyway..